# How to start an android activity through a web application

Tags: android, eclipse, web-applications, client-server

I am making an app that works as an electronic boarding pass.

I created a web application in Eclipse that displays a list of buttons, each representing a passenger that has yet to be boarded.  This pulls the names from a database and updates automatically.

[image]

When I click on a name, which is represented as a button, I want to send the user's information and start up my app's activity passing the name selected on the web page.  The web application will be run on a laptop.

I am new to servers so I am not sure of where to start to make sure that the information is being sent to the tablet I am using.  I am assuming I will need to connect to the MAC address but, I am not sure on how to do that.

My app is completed, I just need to learn how to take care of the client-server connection so any help or links you can provide me would be a great help.  I am not sure how to transfer the information from the web application running on my laptop to the tablet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1) An android side task that communicates to a server the device ip when it is connected to the internet.

2) On the server (web side) a script that is able to communicate to the calling latop the ip of the android device just received.

3) At this point you have everything to start a client / server connection.

I hope I have understood the problem well.

The only problem is that you probably have to create the server with one language and the client in another ... but if you do not have to transmit complicated things it's a secondary problem.

Comment: Do you have any examples to show for this? I guess I am just confused on how to start the connection to the servers or examples of servers to use for the connection.  Is there something else to use besides the IP? Could you possibly use the MAC address or some other hardware id? I have never worked with servers before so this is my first time sending information from one application to another.

Comment: I could put you a link but you could also use the search function. :-)

Search1:

Client / server socket for android example.
.... you need the code for the SERVER part that goes on the smatphone (of course compiled).

Search2:

Client / server socket for c # or vb or Java example
... you need the CLIENT part that will run on the latop.

It does not matter that you use the same language between client and server but you have to use the same protocol (tcp-ip).